# A roller coaster car rises 50 m. If the next rise, after 120 m of travel it is 40 m. What is the maximum allowable friction force for a 500 kg cart ?.

Tags: physics

A roller coaster car rises 50 m. If the
next rise, after 120 m of travel it is 40
m. What is the maximum allowable friction force for
a 500 kg cart ?.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of potential energy between the two points at height difference $\Delta h$ is
$$ \Delta E_{\text{pot}}=mg\Delta h.$$
The work of a force $F$ along a way of length $s$ (and always parallel to the trajectory) is
$$ W=Fs.$$
If we assume that the coaster has no additioal energy (e.g., starts with no kinetic energy at the 60 m point), we must have
$$ W\le E_{\text{pot}}.$$
As $m,g,\Delta h, s$ are known, you can obtain an upper bound for $F$ from this.